# How to load a delimited file with empty fields in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am using the below command to load the file, when I try to dump or illustrate the loaded data, it fails with the below error. I have checked the sanity of the data, each line contains correct number of delimiters, but when the field is empty the delimiter immediately follows , I tried loading the below single sample line. It does not work.

```
hs_2_inr = LOAD 'hs_2_inr.dat' USING PigStorage('^') as ( year:chararray, country:chararray, s_no:chararray, hs_8:chararray, hs_8_desc:chararray, prevyr_inr:chararray, curyr_inr:chararray, growth:chararray, dummy:chararray);
```

Here is the sample data

```
1997^BOTSWANA^1.^10063001^*RICE PARBOILED^^2.43^^
```

Below is the exception

```
2013-06-30 21:02:23,015 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.pen.AugmentBaseDataVisitor - No (valid) input data found!
java.lang.RuntimeException: No (valid) input data found!
    at org.apache.pig.pen.AugmentBaseDataVisitor.visit(AugmentBaseDataVisitor.java:583)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.accept(LOLoad.java:229)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:82)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.util.PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.walk(PreOrderDepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getExamples(ExampleGenerator.java:180)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1180)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.java:739)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigScriptParser.java:626)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:323)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
2013-06-30 21:02:23,016 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Exception
```

so how do I load a file with empty fields in pig?

Comment: Just found that ILLUSTRATE is the culprit, if i run ILLUSTRATE first, it breaks DUMP as well. Whereas, running DUMP without running ILLUSTRATE works fine. Probably a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. As you mentioned in your comment, `ILLUSTRATE` was your problem. Per the [docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#ILLUSTRATE), `ILLUSTRATE` wasn't being maintained for a while. Do not rely on it. You shouldn't need it in any non-diagnostic code anyway. Use `DESCRIBE` instead.

In [newer Pig versions](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/test.html#illustrate), the warning on `ILLUSTRATE` seems to have gone away, so it may be safe again, but I'd still rely more heavily on `DESCRIBE` to avoid a source of potential issues. In Pig 0.10, which I'm on, `ILLUSTRATE` still gave me the same error you received.